# Alarm manager notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Im new to Android development.

In my app i need to have alarm notification.
I have google it, there are many links but i can't understand to start alarm notification at specific time.

I have a five particular times. At this times Alarm sound notify should start.
And alarm sound is my.mp3, i should notify alarm with mp3.

If suppose, i have time like this

```
String time1 = "03:37";
String time2 = "08:45";
String time3 = "13:01";
String time4 = "20:10";
String time5 = "09:08";
```

I tried like this but not working

```
Date dt = new Date();
        int hours = dt.getHours();
        int minutes = dt.getMinutes();
        int seconds = dt.getSeconds();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(hours>=12){                      
            sb.append(hours-12).append( ":" ).append(minutes);
        }else{
            sb.append(hours).append( ":" ).append(minutes);
        }
        String Timeformat = sb.toString();
        curTime = hours+":"+minutes;

if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time1){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}else{
....
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks a lot in advance. Sorry for my grammar mistakes.

Comment: thats all you have for that requirement?! What did you tried so far?

Comment: Have you read the android training yet? http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: @StefanBeike  i tried like above code but its not working

Comment: @Smokez i saw that and read like that only i tried its not working

Comment: is it showing any error

Comment: no its not showing error @Wizard

Comment: if condition u need to close bracket `)` check it

Comment: and did u added this two lines in manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>`
`<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>`

Comment: when 1st time app runs at that time which condition satisfies its alarm itseems.. but time updates but not alarming in other times..  @Wizard

Comment: u r just checking for first condition add other conditions also like u have added only time1 u need to check for time2,time3 .. then it will surly work

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time1)){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
else if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time2)){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
else if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time3)){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
else if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time4)){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
else if(curTime.equalsIngoreCase(time5)){
Intent myIntent =  new Intent(DayView.this, MyAlarmService.class);
                        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(DayView.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
                        AlarmManager alarmManager =  (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```